# GUI for editing multiple JSON files

Tags: text-editor, json, batch

I am looking to edit JSON files in bulk / batch. I know I can do this programmatically, or do find/replaces across files, but I am hoping to find a friendlier GUI that allows me to do things across a selection of files like:

- editing a certain key:
- adding a key
- nice to have: seeing stats of the value of a specific key to quickly spot typo's

Is there something available like this for any OS, or as a webapp?

To clarify what I mean, I have included two example json files below:

File 1:

```
{
    "title": "Some title",
    "categories": [
        "Category 1",
        "Category 2"
    ],
    "specs": [
        "Up",
        "Down",
        "Left",
        43
    ],
    "price: {
        "type": "Upper",
        "amount": 5,
    },
    "delivery: {
        "type": "Pickup",
        "amount": 1,
    },
}
```

File 2:

```
{
    "title": "Some other title",
    "categories": [
        "Category 1",
        "Catergoy 6"
    ],
    "specs": [
        "Up",
        42
    ],
    "price: {
        "type": "Upper",
        "amount": 6,
    },
    "delivery: {
        "type": "Address",
        "amount": 2,
    },
    "status": sold
}
```

I am looking for GUI software that would allow me to e.g.:

- edit the `price.amount` key and set it to `10` for all selected files
- add a key `status` to all files, choosing whether or not I want to overwrite any existing keys
- show all values for the key `category`, such that I can quickly see that there are 3 distinct values of which one has a typo (`Categroy 6`).

Comment: I don't know if this will do what you want (hence not an answer), but I've used it myself for other JSON tasks: https://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/

Answer (score 0):

Various text editors allow you to open several files at once and do find and replace over several. I use Notepad++. Your question is a little vague. Any software that would allow more then find and replace would be so complex to use that you might as well write a script for it.

Batch replace with Notepad++ is explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192543/20944710).

Comment: Thanks. Could you perhaps add how I can do the 3 things listed using find and replace? Also, what can I do to make it more concrete?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke what kind of editing do you need to do exaclty? editing a key probably comes done to just find and replace. if you actually want to manipulate the tree and not just add a new line at a certain position, you will need to parse the file anyway.

maybe give an example file and what should be the results.

Comment: I've added an example, hope that helps clarify what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Kate](https://kate-editor.org/) (from KDE). The application is cross-platform and very functional. But for mass editing of JSON values, it is probably better to write a simple Python script.